# Automatically highlight certain words in Libre/OpenOffice

Tags: macos, openoffice-writer, libreoffice-writer, highlighting

Is there a way to make LibreOffice automatically highlight certain words in some color?

I often write "todo" in files to remind me to come back later and finish something up, etc.

It would be very convenient if LibreOffice highlighted all occurences of todo in a document automatically in red so that I could easily spot the todos without having to search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your asking can be easily done in Notepad++, with a user defined language (UDL).  In LibreOffice this is a little more complicated, but I have a solution.

Load your document in LibreOffice Writer, then click Edit --> Find & Replace from the drop down menu, enter *todo* as the search criteria, and click Find All.

[image: LibreOffice Writer highlight reoccurring words]

From there you can apply a style to the highlighted words. Going further still you could record these actions in a macro, which would be triggered at every save point - using an [Event Driven Macro](https://help.libreoffice.org/Basic/Event-Driven_Macros).  Also you'd probably then need to add something into the Macro to deselect all the *todo* keywords, making it easier to continue once the macro has been ran.